# pandas: binary encode a set of values in pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame my_df:

```
Name      cards
------------------
John      {A,B}
Mary      {B,C,A}
Dan       {D,A}
Peter     {C,A}
Ed        {A,C,D}
```

and I want to do a binary encoding for the set values, i.e. I want the output to be like:

```
Name     Card_A    Card_B    Card_C   Card_D
--------------------------------------------
John      1          1         0        0
Mary      1          1         1        0
Dan       1          0         0        1
Peter     1          0         1        0
Ed        1          0         1        1
```

Is there an existing python package for this? Or what would be the best way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***if `cards` column are `set`s***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Mary','Dan','Peter','Ed'],
                   'cards':[set(['A','B']), set(['B','C','A']), 
                            set(['D','A']), set(['C','A']), set(['A','C','D'])]})


df[['Name']].join(
    df.cards.apply(
        lambda x: pd.value_counts(list(x))
    ).fillna(0).astype(int).add_prefix('Card_')
)
```

[image]

---

***if `cards` column is `str`***
just to showcase parsing with `str.extractall`

parse it with `str.extractall` and `apply` `value_counts`

```
df[['Name']].join(
    df.cards.str.extractall('([^\{\}, ]+)')[0].groupby(level=0).apply(
        pd.value_counts).unstack(fill_value=0).add_prefix('Card_')
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First convert `set`s to `str` and remove `{}` by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html).

Then [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html).

Last [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Mary','Dan','Peter','Ed'],
                   'cards':[set(['A','B']), set(['B','C','A']), 
                            set(['D','A']), set(['C','A']), set(['A','C','D'])]})

print (df)
    Name      cards
0   John     {A, B}
1   Mary  {A, C, B}
2    Dan     {A, D}
3  Peter     {A, C}
4     Ed  {A, D, C}

df.cards = df.cards.astype(str).str.strip('{}')
df = df.set_index('Name').cards.str.get_dummies(', ')
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip("'")
df = df.add_prefix('Card_').reset_index()

print (df)
    Name  Card_A  Card_B  Card_C  Card_D
0   John       1       1       0       0
1   Mary       1       1       1       0
2    Dan       1       0       0       1
3  Peter       1       0       1       0
4     Ed       1       0       1       1
```

Another alternative solution:

```
def f(category_list):
    n_categories = len(category_list)
    return pd.Series(dict(zip(category_list, [1]*n_categories)))

df1 = df.set_index('Name').cards
        .apply(f)
        .add_prefix('Card_')
        .fillna(0)
        .astype(int)
        .reset_index()

print (df1)
    Name  Card_A  Card_B  Card_C  Card_D
0   John       1       1       0       0
1   Mary       1       1       1       0
2    Dan       1       0       0       1
3  Peter       1       0       1       0
4     Ed       1       0       1       1
```